# How to resolve "This content cannot be displayed in a frame" error - CRM 2013 + Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: iframe, sharepoint-2013, dynamics-crm-2013

I am trying to display/embed a Power View report from Sharepoint 2013 'document library' into CRM 2013 dashboard.

CRM 2013 - On Premise, Sharepoint 2013 - On Premise.

Below are the steps I followed:

1. Developed a sample Power View report in Excel 2013 using CRM OData Feed
2. Uploaded the Power View report (.xlsx) to Sharepoint 2013 **Document Library**
3. In CRM, created a System Dashboard and added an IFrame.
4. Copied the Power View report URL and appended "&action=embedview" to the query string.
5. Updated the string above into the CRM Dashboard IFrame URL property. Un-ticked the 'Restrict cross-frame scripting ' check box. Saved and Published the dashboard.

(as suggested in - **[Embedding Power View reports in CRM 2013](http://markmargolis.wordpress.com/2013/11/18/embedding-power-view-reports-in-crm-2013-the-easy-way/)** , **[PowerView reports in CRM](http://www.concurrency.com/blog/powerview-reports-dynamics-crm/)**)

Opening the dashboard in CRM displays 'This content cannot be displayed in a frame' error.

What I have tried so far : 
Changing IE settings  based on -- **[article](http://markmargolis.wordpress.com/2013/01/07/crm-2011-sharepoint-iframe-error/)**

I've seen this one too -- **[IFraming Sharepoint hosted apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2012/12/12/iframing-sharepoint-hosted-pages-in-apps.aspx)** but couldn't to understand what needs to be done. When I tried opening my 'document library' using 'Open in Explorer' and changed the **/Forms/AllItems.aspx** to include the tag below, it broke the document library.

```html
<WebPartPages:AllowFraming runat="server" />
```

Please assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A colleague helped me resolve this issue.

The resolution is installing a "PermissiveXFrameHeader" sharepoint solution and enabling the feature for my sharepoint web app. Please refer to this article **[Sharepoint:Rendering inside iframes](http://www.sharepointblogs.be/blogs/vandest/archive/tags/Excel%20Services/default.aspx)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to create an outbound rule in IIS for the SharePoint app holding the documents. These are the fields I used in creating the outbound rule:

1. Name

   - Any name you want, I used set x-frame-options
2. Match

   - Matching scope: Server Variable
   - Variable name: RESPONSE_X-FRAME-OPTIONS
   - Pattern: .*
   - Action type:

     - Rewrite Action properties Value: (LEAVE BLANK)
     - (CHECK) Replace existing server variable value

Then I just applied the rule. It's working for me at present. Let me know if it works for you.